# Create a column that is equal to the sum of two columns from a separate table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, reference, foreign-keys

I have two tables: Book and Author. The BookAuthor column in the Book table needs to be equal to the AuthorFirstName column combined with the AuthorLastName column from the Author table. I am not sure how to do this. I tried setting a UNIQUE constraint on the AuthorFirstName and AuthorLastName columns so I can reference them in the Book table, but I got an error. Please let me know a better method or what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE Author 

(

   AuthorId INT IDENTITY(1,1),

   AuthorFirstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

   AuthorLastName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT Author_pk PRIMARY KEY (AuthorId)

);

CREATE TABLE Book

(
    BookID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 

    BookTitle VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL, 

    BookAuthor (I don't know what goes here!!)

    CONSTRAINT Book_Id PRIMARY KEY(BookId)  

);
```

Comment: Books can have more than one author.

Comment: See [Normalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description).  *"...Redundant data wastes disk space and creates maintenance problems. If data that exists in more than one place must be changed, the data must be changed in exactly the same way in all locations..."*

Answer (score 2):

Don't copy the author name onto the Book table.  It should simply be:

```
CREATE TABLE Author 
(
   AuthorId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
   FirstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   LastName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT Author_pk PRIMARY KEY (AuthorId)
);

CREATE TABLE Book
(
    BookID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
    Title VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL, 
    AuthorId int references Author(AuthorId),
    INDEX ix_BookAuthorId (AuthorId),
    CONSTRAINT Book_pk PRIMARY KEY(BookId)  
);
```

You can always join them, or even create a view, like this

```
create or alter view vBook
as
select b.BookID, b.Title, concat(a.FirstName, ' ', a.LastName) AuthorName
from Book b
join Author a
  on b.AuthorId = a.AuthorId
```